# watermark text font size on image with same dimensions but different dpi

Tags: c#, watermark

I am trying to add two watermark texts on images, one at the bottom left and the other at bottom right side of the image irrespective of the image dimensions. Following is my method:

```
public void AddWaterMark(string leftSideText, string rightSideText, string imagePath)
{
    string firstText = leftSideText;
    string secondText = rightSideText;

    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imagePath);//load the image file

    PointF firstLocation = new PointF((float)(bitmap.Width * 0.035), bitmap.Height - (float)(bitmap.Height * 0.06));
    PointF secondLocation = new PointF(((float)((bitmap.Width / 2) + ((bitmap.Width / 2) * 0.6))), bitmap.Height - (float)(bitmap.Height * 0.055));

    int opacity = 155, baseFontSize = 50;
    int leftTextSize = 0, rightTextSize = 0;
    leftTextSize = (bitmap.Width * baseFontSize) / 1920;
    rightTextSize = leftTextSize - 5;
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        Font arialFontLeft = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, leftTextSize);
        Font arialFontRight = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, rightTextSize);
        graphics.DrawString(firstText, arialFontLeft, new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(opacity, Color.White)), firstLocation);
        graphics.DrawString(secondText, arialFontRight, new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(opacity, Color.White)), secondLocation);
    }
    string fileLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/Albums/") + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imagePath) + "_watermarked" + Path.GetExtension(imagePath);
    bitmap.Save(fileLocation);//save the image file
    bitmap.Dispose();
    if (File.Exists(imagePath))
    {
        File.Delete(imagePath);
        File.Move(fileLocation, fileLocation.Replace("_watermarked", string.Empty));
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is with setting `font size` of the water mark text properly. Lets say there are two images with `1600 x 900` pixels dimensions and the first image has a `dpi` of `72` and the second image has `dpi` of `240`. The above method is working fine for the image with `72` dpi but for the image with `240` `dpi`, the `font size` of the watermark text becomes too big and overflows on the image. How to calculate `font size` correctly with images of different `dpi` but has the same dimensions?

Comment: So you effectively want the font to be smaller for larger DPI values? (Font size in pixels rather than DPI dependent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple trick should work:

**Before** applying the text set the `dpi` of the image.
**After** applying the text **reset** it to the previous values.

```
float dpiXNew = 123f;
float dpiYNew = 123f;

float dpiXOld = bmp.HorizontalResolution;
float dpiYOld = bmp.VerticalResolution;

bmp.SetResolution(dpiXNew, dpiYNew);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    TextRenderer.DrawText(g, "yourText", ....)
    ...
}

bmp.SetResolution(dpiXOld, dpiYOld);
```